# Angular2: How to set [(ngModel)] based on which Model property has a value and what type of option object is chosen

Tags: javascript, angular, ngmodel, angular2-ngmodel

I have a `<select>` tag with options that are of two different type of objects. I want the `[(ngModel)]` to be binded to the same Object but to different properties of that object. For example `[(ngModel)]` would be `Object.type1ID` if the chosen option is of `type1` and the `[(ngModel)]` would be `Object.type2ID` if the chosen option is of `type2`

Comment: Can you post some code

Comment: Welcome to StackOverflow! Please make sure to add a minimal verifiable code snippet for others to take a look and understand your problem. For more details on how to create [mcve] check this.

Answer (score 2):

Since you didn't provide code I post my answer based on some assumption
I assume your select is like `<select #myselect ...>` and your object name is `myObject`

Then you can use the below code

```
[(ngModel)]="myObject[myselect.value]"
```

please see the working code [here](https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-dynamic-ngmodel)